# Raspberry Pi VNC login info

Tags: vnc

I have set up a correct VNC server, but when i try to login to it on my Mac it asks for login info. i tried using pi and the username and raspberry as the password but it did not work. Is there a way to figure out the login info through the Pi its self?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your network configuration but just with a mac you have a big chance that it is configured with self assigned ip addresses. Then you will find the RasPi with the name `raspberrypi.local` on your network. The default password is `raspberry` of course.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you setup VNC you can login with

```
open vnc://pi@IP:5901
```

or

```
open vnc://pi@raspberrypi.local:5901
```

VNC has its own password which you set on install.

I use `tightvncserver`, and the first time you use it you run `vncpasswd`which stores encrypted password in `~.vnc/passwd`.

If you use the RealVNC included with Pi you need to install RealVNCviewer on Mac